# Chrome putting black backgrounds on my input boxes

Tags: html, css

Every site I am working on has a black input boxes all of a sudden in Chrome.
My research points to the fact that it might be a webkit issue. But I can't tell and don't
know what to do about it.
Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Are you using a special UI theme?

Comment: Do you have a link to one of your sites?

Comment: I don't want to get in trouble for advertising faults to the site. Is it possible that because I'm looking at it internally the stylesheets are getting processed differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK admittedly a dummy, I accidentally hit "high contrast" extension in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed this. There's always the simple uninstall and re-install Chrome, but you could also use the following CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {
    background-color:white; /* or whatever colour you choose */
}
```

Comment: thanks... css is already set. It appears I'm the only one with this problem, so I must assume it's a setting in my browser - something I have not fiddled with so it's odd.